# Operator and interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm going to speak very informally, because i don't know how to formalize this stuff.

If we have knots $X = \left\{ x_0, \ldots x_n \right\}$ and a given function $f$ belonging to an appropriate function space we know that we can derive $Y = \left\{ f(x_0) = f_0, \ldots, f(x_n) = f_n \right\}$ and using an interpolating function $g(x) = \sum_j \alpha_j g_j(x)$ to interpolate $f$ in the nodes $X$. We also know that we have to solve

$$ A \vec{\alpha} = \vec{f},$$

where, using the Cramer rule

$$ \alpha_j = \frac{det(A_j)}{det(A)}.$$

For given model $g$ and set $X$ i guess we can define an operator $T_{g,X}$ such that

$$ T_{j,g,X} f = \alpha_j g_j.$$

My question is would be that possible to define a proper hilbert space such that the operator $T_{j,g,X}$ is a normal/hermitian operator etc? Is there some study about it?